# Can't get to Dell OMSA GUI on my Linux server

Tags: centos, dell-openmanage

Running Centos 6.7 Linux and installed OSMA

```
wget -q -O - http://linux.dell.com/repo/hardware/Linux_Repository_15.07.00/bootstrap.cgi | bash
yum install srvadmin-all
```

No errors, installed fine but after opening TCP IN / OUT port 1311 in CSF firewall, still cannot access https://serverip:1311

Worked fine on another Centos box, but with exceptions. That one, not giving off any info that I need like hardware status, etc.

Screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIN3H.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Cazzette -

I just installed OSMA on CentOS 7 and I got the same thing. There was nothing for port 1311 when i did a netstat -anp| grep LISTEN and then I went looking for the services. I found them in /etc/init.d/ and there are four relevant services that you will need to start (and have start with the system ideally).

Run these commands and try it again:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/dataeng start
sudo /etc/init.d/dsm_om_connsvc start
sudo /etc/init.d/dsm_om_shrsvc start
sudo /etc/init.d/dsm_sa_ipmi start
```